# Is it possible to modify PHP's $_SESSION variable by client

Tags: php, session

The `$_SESSION['isLogin']` default value is `0`.

I want to modify the `$_SESSION['isLogin']` value to `1`
(not in the script)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['isLogin'] == 1 {
        echo "Hello";
    } else {
        echo "You need login before enter this page !";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to modify that value you need to assign a new value to the variable. So what is it you actually ask for? A way to alter values in a script that ignores the actual code that is implemented?

Comment: Sorry, i will fix it

Comment: And what does "not in the script" actually mean?

Comment: I think he/she is asking if a web browser can set the value of a session variable? The answer to that is simply: No.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can modify the value of `$_SESSION` variable.You can try for

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['isLogin'] = 1; 
     if(isset($_SESSION['isLogin'])) {
        echo "Hello";
    } else {
        echo "You need login before enter this page !";
    }
```